# Delphi TPrinter and error 217

Tags: delphi, printing, runtime-error

Can anybody explain how this should work (Delphi XE2 running on Windows10)?

In a minimalist application - a form with two buttons - with the following code:

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Printer.BeginDoc;
  Printer.Canvas.TextOut(10,10,'Hello World');
  Printer.EndDoc;
end;

procedure TForm2.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  MyPrinter : TPrinter;
begin
  MyPrinter := Printer;
  MyPrinter.BeginDoc;
  MyPrinter.Canvas.TextOut(10,10,'Hello World');
  MyPrinter.EndDoc;
  MyPrinter.Free;
end;
```

If I click Button1, the program prints a 'Hello World' at my default printer, and closes normally when I close it (with the close button). If instead, I click Button2, the program prints an identical page but now when I close with the close button I get an Error 217 message.

I can't find clarification in the Delphi documentation regarding exactly how to use the Printer function and TPrinter variables. I am quite happy using a derivative of the Button1 technique to print - if it is confirmed that this is the 'bullet-proof' way to go, but would like to understand why the Button2 method doesn't work. Should I just assume that it is not *my* responsibility to free any TPrinter object I instantiate, or is there a clearer explanation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you are running this code:

```
  MyPrinter := Printer;
  MyPrinter.BeginDoc;
  MyPrinter.Canvas.TextOut(10,10,'Hello World');
  MyPrinter.EndDoc;
  MyPrinter.Free;
```

`Printer` is deleted on function exit. So when appication is terminating, it tries to delete it again, and you get an error. More than that, if you try to run this code second time, it will raise as well. `MyPrinter` is just a pointer to the global `TPrinter` object, returned by the `Printer` function. You should not delete things, that you have not created.

Documentation of the `Printer` function:

> Returns a global instance of TPrinter to manage interaction with the
>   printer.
>
> Printer creates an instance of a global TPrinter object the first time
>   it is called. Use the Printer function to print using the TPrinter
>   object.
>
> Note: The global TPrinter object is freed automatically when the
>   application shuts down. After a call to SetPrinter, the printer that
>   is returned is not automatically freed. It is the caller's
>   responsibility to either free the return value, or replace it using
>   another call to SetPrinter and to free the substitute printer that the
>   second SetPrinter call returns.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, the Printer function just returns a pre-created TPrinter object that is set up to match the default printer. And it should not be considered in any way as a TPrinter factory, so to speak. Then am I correct if I just use Printer as if it is a global variable of type TPrinter (rather than a function as described in the Delphi help)?

Comment: Yes indeed. Printer function returns an instance of global `TPrinter` object, which is created on the first use. It is freed automatically on application exit, as long as you have not used `SetPrinter` function.

Comment: @Penguino the `Printer()` function returns a `TPrinter` singleton object that the RTL owns for you. Just use the `TPrinter` as needed. And you are not limited to just the default printer, either. You can set the `TPrinter.PrinterIndex` property to work with other printers.

Comment: @Ari0nhh Thanks all. It is all clear now. Can you point out where you find the documentation you quoted? Under http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Vcl.Printers.Printer (or the older XE2 version of the help files that F1 directs me to) there is no 'Note:', just the comment "Printer is declared in the Printers unit. To use the Printer function and the TPrinter object, add Printers to the uses clause of your unit (Delphi) or include Printers.hpp in the source file (C++)." ... which is less than useful.

Comment: @Penguino I have used help topics for the `Printer` and `SetPrinter` functions: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Vcl.Printers.Printer http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Vcl.Printers.SetPrinter